# onclick="this.closest("form").submit()" does not fire when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, form-submit

I have following

```
<div  class="delete_list left" onclick="this.closest("form").submit()">
  <form action="deletelist.php" method="post" name="deletelist">
    <input type="hidden" name="second_id" value="'.$row_second['second_id'].'">
  </form>
</div>
```

When i click div `submit()` does not work. Interestingly below code works perfect.

```
<div  class="delete_list left" onclick="document.forms['deletelist'].submit()">
  <form action="deletelist.php" method="post" name="deletelist">
    <input type="hidden" name="second_id" value="'.$row_second['second_id'].'">
  </form>
</div>
```

I couldn't understand the difference.Thanks.

Comment: Wait, you mean ***below*** code works perfect. The code above doesn't work because the form is not a parent of the DIV, and `this` is not a jQuery object, but why not just use the bottom code ?

Comment: bcause there is many `name="deletelist"` divin the page. And i used `$(this)` instead. It failed again. and yes its below

Comment: @adeneo you're right, check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

The **[closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** is a jquery function That go up and not down so it can't target the element inside like `form` in your example.

So your code will **[work](https://jsfiddle.net/53c7fh0w/)** if you change `closest` to `find` so you can go down and change javascript object `this` to jquery object `$(this)` and finally fix the double quotes conflit :

```
<div  class="delete_list left" onclick="$(this).find('form').submit()">
```

But i suggest for you to avoid the use of `inline-event` since it's not recommended and use the `on` click event :

```
<div class="delete_list left">
    <form action="deletelist.php" method="post" name="deletelist">
        <input type="hidden" name="second_id" value="'.$row_second['second_id'].'">
    </form>
</div>

$('body').on('click', '.left', function(){
    $(this).find("form").submit();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i already know it can be written like that but i want why my code does not work.

Comment: closest() is equivalent of parents() that select parents elements and not childs.

Comment: damn lost 30 min. for a cinch

Comment: Is this post not answering your question @WebberDepor ?